# What is the best way to generate html using my own data?

Tags: html, code-generation

I have a static website with a list of items where each item is the same style, just a new id or something like that. I currently just copy and paste an old item in the list and change its contents to add items, but it feel archaic to do something so procedural by hand. Is there some kind of framework that allows for making a file with the items I want and specifying the html for each item and then generating it to then get the index.html for my static site? I could write a python script I know, but I feel like there is something that exists for this already that I don't know about.

Comment: since it's not coding related question, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit for it.

Comment: Broad question, you could create a jQuery function to do the heavy lifting for you and just load items data in objects (similar to a JSON data), would this be something you'd consider or don't want any code involved at all?

Comment: thanks, both of you. @Syden, I think it would be a waste of client resources to do that every page load. I'm fine generating it myself before pushing the site, but I'm interested in reading about what you're suggesting since I actually don't have that experience with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Generic example of jQuery dynamically generated HTML item list (*Please comment if not suitable and I'll remove*).

1. Place item data in object (could be title, link, img, description, etc).
2. Add each new item to items array.
3. Loop through items array generating HTML dynamically.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //initialize function
  showItems();
})

//add data to object
var item1 = {
  img: 'https://placehold.it/100x100',
  id: '#img'
};
var item2 = {
  img: 'https://placehold.it/100x100',
  id: '#img2'
};
var item3 = {
  img: 'https://placehold.it/100x100',
  id: '#img3'
};
var item4 = {
  img: 'https://placehold.it/100x100',
  id: '#img4'
};

//add objects to array
var items = [item1, item2, item3, item4];

//loop through array and generate html
function showItems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('.flex-container').append('<li><img src="' + items[i].img + '"><h3>' + items[i].id + '</h3></li>');
  }
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container li {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="flex-container"></ul>
```